# Sinon.js set exact behavior of mock

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

Im testing some unit in my js code using Sinon.

And the question is - how can I change behavior of mocked object's method?

For example, i have some object, that have the `reject` method. I want him to return some calculated value, and expect, that it called once with proper context. I do the folowing:

```
var myObj = {reject: function(){
  // here original behavior
}};

sinon.stub(myObj, 'reject', function() {
  // here my test behavior
});

sinon.mock(myObj).expects('reject').once().on(someContext);
```

But finally im getting error: `TypeError: Attempted to wrap reject which is already spied on`

How can I solve my task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to stub a method TWICE. You would want to add your expectations to the result of the first stub:

```
var myObj = {reject: function(){
    // here original behavior
}};

myObjStub = sinon.stub(myObj, 'reject', function() {
    // here my test behavior
});

myObjStub.once().on(someContext);
```

I *think* if you want to basically stub a custom behavior ('here my test behavior' and then ensure that it is called once you do:

```
var myObj = {reject: function(){
    // here CUSTOM behavior
}};

myObjStub = sinon.mock(myObj);
myObjStub.once().on(someContext);
```

Comment: Yes, this is works fine. But, as documentation said, mocks api extends stubs. How can I do the same thing via mocking that object? Thank you, anyway =)

Comment: hmm, so...you want to basically stub a custom behavior ('here my test behavior' and then ensure that it is called once?

Comment: Yeah, but with mock =) Its impossible? )